# Unable to cast object of type 'DapperRow' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm using Dapper to access database objects.

So this line

```
Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, results));
```

Gives me

```
{DapperRow, VALUE_A = 'Y', VALUE_B = 'Y'}
```

But i'd like to access or print these values like

```
DapperRow, 
VALUE_A = 'Y'
VALUE_B = 'Y'
```

But I am getting "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'DapperRow' to type 'System.String'" with the following code. Where i am trying to use foreach to loop through this list.

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Data Source=xxxxx"))
{
// dapper adds an extension method to the connection for querying
string sql = "SELECT X, Y FROM Z WHERE ABC = 123";
var results = conn.Query(sql).ToList();
Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, results));

    foreach (string value in results)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("> {0}",value);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe I'm asking the wrong question but what does that query return in a sql tool? IE what are the data types? I've not used Dapper like you are using but normally bind to an object without issue

Comment: In an sql tool, i get one row with two columns where 'VALUE_A' and 'VALUE_B' are the headings and 'Y' are the values.

Comment: what happens when you have a `class Foo{ public string X; public string Y;}` then do `conn.QueryMultiple(...).Read<Foo>().ToList(); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this gives me the result i want..

```
using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxxx;Data Source=xxxxxx"))
{
string sql = "SELECT X, Y FROM Z WHERE ABC = 123";
var orderDetail = conn.Query(sql).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (var pair in orderDetail)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    }
}

Output: 
VALUE_A = 'Y'
VALUE_B = 'Y'
```

Then with something like this i can get a value of 'Y' returned.

```
if (pair.Key == "VALUE_B")
{
Console.WriteLine("Val {0}", pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is late but I just solved a similar issue I was facing and thought to share.
With Dapper, you can transform object into the needed type on Query. So write a class with the properties X, Y

```
class DataReturned
{
public string X {get; set;}
public string Y {get; set;}
}
```

Then when querying you do this

```
var results = conn.Query<DataReturned>(sql).ToList();
```

instead of this

```
var results = conn.Query(sql).ToList();
```

This will remove the DapperRow and give you just the list you can use.
You may not need the class if you only want one value which you cast to a primitive type

```
var results = conn.Query<string>(sql).ToList();
```

Am sure you can even cast to string array, dictionary or any other type, just have not experimented that.

Answer (score 0):

Citing [the manual](http://dapper-tutorial.net/querymultiple) as reference:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; SELECT * FROM InvoiceItem WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;";

using (var connection = My.ConnectionFactory())
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {InvoiceID = 1}))
    {
        var invoice = multi.Read<Invoice>().First();
        var invoiceItems = multi.Read<InvoiceItem>().ToList();
    }
}
```

would mean that your code would change to something like

```
        string sql = "SELECT X, Y FROM Z WHERE ABC = @ABC";
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Password=xxxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Data Source=xxxxx"))
        using (var multi = conn.QueryMultiple(sql, new {ABC = 123}))
        {
            var results = multi.Read<Z>().ToList();
            Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, results.Count));
            foreach (string value in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("> X:{0} Y:{1}",value.X, value.Y);
            }
        }
```